# Visiting brother in Korea, transit 2 days

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, south-korea, stopovers

I am an Indian citizen, residing in Japan, having permanent residency in Japan. I am planning to visit Hong Kong via South Korea.

I want to break my journey in Seoul for 2-3 days on the way to Hong Kong (Osaka, Seoul, Hong Kong, Osaka). Can you please guide me on this issue?

Will I be granted a 30-day transit visa at Seoul airport upon arrival, since I am in transit, going onward to Hong Kong after 3 days, and having PR in Japan?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

No. The 30-day exemption is only valid for people with a visa/residence permit from Australia, Canada, New Zealand, or the USA. Japan is not in the list.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#30-day_visa_exemption